# Login from Facebook plugins without popup window

Tags: facebook, iframe, authentication, popup, facebook-like

I'm using [Facebook like plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

When user clicks the Like button, when he isn't logged in, Facebook will show a log-in popup window.

How can I customize the this behavior, to open the log-in page in the same window or in an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Due to fact that Facebook social plugins rendered in `iframe` tag you have no control over this and Facebook doesn't provide way to customize that behavior.